# How can I retrieve recorded/archived values from PI server using Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve one archived value from PI server using PIConnect package in Python.
However, the result is always an empty series even when there is data in the specified date/range.

Here is the code I tried to retrieve one value

```
with PI.PIServer(server='servername') as server:
for point in server.search("*"):
            if point.tag == 'tagname':
                data = point.recorded_values('4/29/2021 10:23:00 PM', '4/29/2021 10:23:00 PM',  boundary_type = "inside")
                print(data)
```

I also tried the following to retrieve multiple values in a range:

```
with PI.PIServer(server='servername') as server:
for point in server.search("*"):
            if point.tag == 'tagname':
                data = point.recorded_values('4/29/2021 10:23:00 PM', '4/29/2021 10:24:00 PM',  boundary_type = "inside")
                print(data)
```

Both giving me same empty result:
`Series([], Name: tagname, dtype: float64)`

Could you please help.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am working on something similar.